# How to get process scheduler history in Solaris?

Tags: process, solaris, scheduler

I would like to know if there is way to get the process sheduler history in Solaris operating system. The output may have the following details.

```
user : user name who invoked the process
name : name of the process / command used to invoke the process
loc  : location or path of the binary
pid  : process id
event: event happened to the process (init, suspend or end)
time : time the event happend
date : date the event happeed
```

I'm interested to hear if any such thing available for other OS as well.

Answer (score 1):

You might implement that with a `dtrace` script leveraging the [proc provider](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/DTrace/proc+Provider) (`proc:::exec-success`, `proc:::exit` and `proc:::signal_handle`).

Your event list looks dubious, should probably be at least "`start`,`suspend`,`resume` and `exit`"

Answer (score 1):

You want the audit feature of Solaris. man audit and associated utilities, auditconfig etc